# Locate point along line in multiple self-intersection area

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I've a not simple linestring geometry with multiple self-intersections.

Given a point that sits on a multiple self intersecting vertice of this linestring, I'd like to have an output like st_linelocatepoint but with multiple results, one for every part of the line that this point really intersects.

The only way I can visualize is something like this, where I need to ***somehow*** calculate new locations of points.

---

For example, *assuming that ST_LineLocatePoint always gives back the same result*, as it seems, **but please comment on this** (Can I trust the fact that this function always gives me the lowest location available as it seems?) having this situation,

```
WITH example AS (
    SELECT 
    1 as fid, 
    ST_GeometryFromText('LINESTRING (598798.2596144932 4884266.409449324, 598773.5767953519 4884233.541530695, 598743.5323493142 4884209.236759994, 598712.3417874083 4884183.797536587, 598739.2549513935 4884169.584966842, 598743.5323493142 4884209.236759994, 598746.5124338163 4884263.327448138, 598798.2596144932 4884266.409449324, 598802.6067250437 4884218.572973198, 598743.5323493142 4884209.236759994, 598696.1636495071 4884208.593934866, 598708.108255995 4884189.089450854, 598743.5323493142 4884209.236759994, 598765.8657202775 4884239.438235163, 598798.2596144932 4884266.409449324)', 32632) as geom
)
SELECT
    (ST_DumpPoints(e.geom)).path as vertex_number,
    ST_LineLocatePoint(e.geom,
        (ST_DumpPoints(e.geom)).geom) loc,
    (ST_DumpPoints(e.geom)).geom as point_geom,
    e.geom as line_geom
FROM
    example e
WHERE
    e.fid = 1;
```

and assuming `results`  as the results of the above query, for every point collection in the following query records, their location should be reevaluated as `loc + (1/total_number_of_points) * point_number`.. *I guess*.

```
 SELECT ST_Collect(point_geom) 
 FROM results 
 GROUP BY loc HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

What could go wrong?

Are there better ways?

Comment: Please clarify what points you are referring to - note that self-intersecting *LineStrings* are not *simple* (which is the validity definition of geometries with dimension < 2 as per OGC; `ST_IsValid` does **not** cover this definition of simplicity, you have to use `ST_IsSimple`!) and thus cannot have any *Point* **intersecting multiple parts** of it. Even with intersections, the only *Point*s being candidates for that are the actual intersection points - is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Given the one line L, starting, ending and self intersecting 4 times in the same point A, i'd like to retrieve the location of A as fraction of total L length, the result should be 6 records with different locations from 0 to 1.. I understand that the actual distribution along the line of the actual intersection point will be totally arbitrary.

Comment: i'd like to create a distribution table of nodes along lines, but lines are not simple, they can self intersect  many times... and yes now i get your answer, every point A sits on self intersection point of L.

Comment: Maybe you can try to cut you geom by the intersections (using ST_Split) and compute the wanted distances by adding the length of the sub-lines that you obtain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also ST_Split return just one element in that case, I solved like this
I post here if someone need help just ask..

assume that exists a table of nodes and a table of lines.

this is a trigger function to compile a schema.segments table,

```
-- table
    CREATE TABLE schema.segments (
    fid int4 NOT NULL,
    partiallength float8 NULL,
    ord int4 NOT NULL,
    geom public.geometry NULL,
 );
```

where all linestring are split into segments, with order of segment
and percentage of total length.

```
 -- function
     CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.compile_segments()
     RETURNS trigger
     LANGUAGE plpgsql
     AS $function$
     begin
         if TG_OP = 'DELETE' then 
            delete from schema.segments  e where e.fid = new.fid;
         else 
             delete from schema.segments  e where e.fid = new.fid;
             insert into schema.segments values (
            new.fid,
            st_length((st_dumpsegments(new.geom)).geom)/ st_length(new.geom),
            unnest((st_dumpsegments(new.geom)).path),
            (st_dumpsegments(new.geom)).geom
            );
             return new;
          end if;
         end;
     $function$
     ;
```

and here there's a function to get all locations along self
intersecting lines of a node that's on one of this lines vertices.

```
create or replace function schema.locations_along_lines(linesfid int4, nodefid int4) returns table (loc decimal) as $$
             begin
                 return query
                with 
                starts as ( -- all segments starting from my node
                    select es.fid efid, es.ord segnum from schema.nodes nodes 
                    join schema.segments es on nodes.geom = st_startpoint(es.geom)
                    where es.fid = linesfid and  nodes.fid = nodefid), 
                ends as ( -- all segments ending on my node
                    select es.fid efid, es.ord segnum from schema.nodes nodes 
                    join schema.segments es on nodes.geom = st_endpoint(es.geom)
                    where es.fid = linesfid and nodes.fid = nodefid)
                select 
                
                (select sum(es.partiallength) from schema.segments es where es.ord <= ends.segnum and es.fid = starts.efid)::decimal as loc 
    -- sum all partial lenghts found in segments table for all segment before
                
                from starts join ends on starts.segnum = ends.segnum + 1 where starts.efid = ends.efid -- join starts and ends to obtain only one
         result per linesfid
                union all 
                select 
                0::decimal as loc -- loc equal 0 for all linesfid that starts on the interested node
                from starts where starts.segnum = 1
                union all  
                select 
                1::decimal as loc -- loc equal 1 for all linesfid that ends on the interested node
                from ends where ends.segnum = (select max(es.ord) from schema.segments es where es.fid = linesfid);
                 
             end;
             $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If someone finds a better solution, or finds that this is not a
solution at all please write here, for clarification as well.